# Extending the User model in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I've linked a `UserProfile` to a `user`. However, I do not like having to jump back and forth in the templates to get first_name, last_name, etc. I would like to use the `User` model for only `auth-related` stuff, and `UserProfile` for all information related to the user (mostly, the display of the user information).

I was wondering if someone could evaluate how my current `UserProfile` model is, and where I could improve it or where it is redundant, etc. Thank you.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    network = models.ForeignKey(Network)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    graduation = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, choices=YEAR)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True,)
    positions = models.ManyToManyField(Position, through ='Timestamp', blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)

    @property
    def get_first_name(self):
        return self.user.first_name

    @property
    def get_last_name(self):
        return self.user.last_name

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name

    @property
    def get_date_joined(self):
        return self.user.date_joined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the "get" prefix on properties. Also, don't forget that you can't query on properties, so you'll need to join to `User` for those. Perhaps you may want to [add some custom queries to your manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods) for that.

Comment: thanks for the comment and the pointer on not being able to query over those read-only fields. What would I need to add to be able to do something like `UserProfile.objects.order_by('first_name','last_name')`?

Comment: ["Lookups that span relationships"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: Thanks a lot. `UserProfile.objects.order_by('-user__last_name')`

Comment: what is the reason not to use the "get" prefix on properties?

Comment: Properties are not getters. They are read from and/or assigned to directly, so there is no "action".